# Открытый текст одной ссылки по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт, который раскрывает текст по нажатию на ссылку.
Как сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию один всегда был открыт (первая ссылка)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {                                                  
    $('.view-source .hide').hide();
    $('.view-source a').on('click', function() {
        $('.view-source .hide').slideUp(500);
        $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="view-source">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>
<div class="view-source">
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>
<div class="view-source">
    <a href="#">333</a>
    <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/xsjukbc0/

Comment: А можно по другому http://jsfiddle.net/gqk34nzn/

Comment: спасибо, это то что нужно

Comment: Добавили бы ответ что ли...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размещу тогда я ответом. Идея в том, чтобы при загрузке страницы скрывать не все блоки текста, а "все кроме первого":

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $texts = $('.view-source .hide');
    $texts.not(':first').hide();
    $('.view-source a').on('click', function () {
        $texts.slideUp(500);
        $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="view-source">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>
<div class="view-source">
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>
<div class="view-source">
    <a href="#">333</a>
    <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- `.parent()` - достаточно негибкое решение (в случае изменения HTML-структуры блока код может сломаться). Имеет смысл использовать вместо этого `.closest('.view-source')`.
- Так как элемент с классом `hide` может быть виден на экране, имеет смысл переименовать класс, дав ему более правильное название для обозначения блока текста. Например, `text`.